# Issue running a java program from a batch script

Tags: java, batch-file

I have a problem with a batch script that runs a java program, here some key lines of the script:

```
exeFinder="java -client -classpath './classes:./lib/javacsv.jar' -Xmx7200m Finder.Main ";
runFinder() {
    cleanFolders;
    $exeFinder $1 $2 $3 > $4;
}
dbName=$1;
k=$2;
n=$3;
outFile="simple_tester-out.log";

runFinder $dbName $k $n $outFile;
```

I run the script with its arguments:
`./myScript.sh testing_7x8.csv 7 8`
And I get this:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class Finder.Main
```

It looks like a java problem, so I change the line `$exeFinder $1 $2 $3 > $4;` for `echo "$exeFinder $1 $2 $3 > $4";` to get my execution line:

```
java -client -classpath './classes:./lib/javacsv.jar' -Xmx7200m Finder.Main  testing_7x8.csv 7 8 > simple_tester-out.log
```

And it works like a charm! So I don't know what is happening.

I have checked some questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21244748/issue-running-java-program-from-batch-file-runs-fine-in-ide) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3799172/run-a-java-program), but I can't see anything useful for me.

Thanks for your time, guys

Comment: sounds like a working directory vs classpath issue to me. whats the working directory the java process is run in? given that wd, are "./classes" and "./lib/javacsv.jar" valid paths?

Comment: yes, they are valid, I'm using the same directory for run the script and for run the "direct way" typing `java - client -clas.....` directly on the terminal. and the last form works fine. BTW, I have found the problem, or at least a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a little problem with the simple quotes in the execution variable, so instead of:

```
"java -client -classpath './classes:./lib/javacsv.jar' -Xmx7200m Finder.Main "
```

it must be:

```
"java -client -classpath ./classes:./lib/javacsv.jar -Xmx7200m Finder.Main "
```

It is probably something related with bash and how it works, I don't know enough to explain why this happens, but that change solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try `sh $exeFinder $1 $2 $3 > $4;`

In my testing, I was unable to directly execute a command in a variable, but I could pass it to sh.

Comment: this didn't work for me, please notice that $exeFinder is a variable that starts with `java -client.....` so it is like type in the console `sh java -classpath....` which make no sense to the console, in fact, it returns `sh: 0: Can't open java`

Comment: Ah, yeah, that makes sense. I only got as far as testing running a basic command (`cd ..`) from a variable, and assumed that was the problem when it didn't work for me (and running via `sh $variable` did). Glad you did find the answer :-)